# VBA print sheets in Alpha order fails. This array is fixed or temporarily locked (Error 10)

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook has 163 Sheets of which 16 are Visible. I would like to print these 16 visible sheets to a single pdf in sheetname Alphabetical Order.

My code is failing with a Runtime 10 error at line

```vb
' Print each visible worksheet to the PDF file in alphabetical order
   For Each wsname In wsname
```

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help.

```vb
    Sub PrintVisibleSheetsToSinglePDF()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim wsname As Variant
        Dim pdfPath As String
        Dim pdfFileName As String
        Dim pdfFullPath As String
        Dim wsCount As Integer
        wsCount = 0
        
        ' Set the path where the PDF will be saved
        pdfPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
        
        ' Create an array to store the visible worksheet names
        ReDim wsname(1 To Worksheets.Count) As Variant
        
        ' Store the visible worksheet names in the array
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                wsname(ws.Index) = ws.Name
                wsCount = wsCount + 1
            End If
        Next ws
        
        ' Sort the visible worksheet names in alphabetical order
        For i = 1 To wsCount - 1
            For j = i + 1 To wsCount
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Name < ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Move before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            
            End If
        Next j
        Next i
    
        ' Create a PDF file name based on the visible sheet names
        pdfFileName = "VisibleSheets_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
        
        ' Set the full path of the PDF file
        pdfFullPath = pdfPath & pdfFileName & ".pdf"
        
        ' Print each visible worksheet to the PDF file in alphabetical order
        For Each wsname In wsname
            If Not IsEmpty(wsname) Then
                Worksheets(wsname).PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:= _
                    "Microsoft Print to PDF", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=pdfFullPath
            End If
        Next wsname
       
       MsgBox "PDF created successfully!"
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing because `For Each wsname In wsname` is invalid syntax: `wsname` is an array that contains the names of your sheets, but the running variable needs to be a different variable. Declare a new variable:

```
Dim tmpWsname As Variant
For Each tmpWsname in wsname 
    (...)
Next
```

However, If I were you, I would rename the array to `wsNames` (to reflect that it hold multiple names)

```
Dim wsNames As Variant
ReDim wsNames(1 To Worksheets.Count) As Variant
(...)
```

and now you can use `wsName` as running variable:

```
Dim wsName As Variant
For Each wsName in wsNames
    (...)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks but now fails here  - ' Store the visible worksheet names in the array
        
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            ***    wsName(ws.Index) = ws.Name ***
                wsCount = wsCount + 1
            End If
        Next ws

Comment: What fails? You get a runtime error? Which error? Have you debugged your code?

Answer (score 0):

### Print Visible Sheets (Sorted) to PDF

[image]

**Main**

```vb
Sub PrintVisibleSheetsToSinglePDF()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const DST_LEFT_TITLE As String = "VisibleSheets_"
    Const DST_TIME_PATTERN As String = "yyyymmdd_hhmmss"
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Store the PDF file name in a variable.
    Dim dFolderPath As String:
    dFolderPath = swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    Dim dFileName As String:
    dFileName = DST_LEFT_TITLE & Format(Now, DST_TIME_PATTERN)
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dFolderPath & dFileName
    
    ' Return the names of the visible sheets in an array
    ' and sort them in ascending order.
    Dim dshNames() As String: dshNames = VisibleSheetNamesInArray(swb)
    BubbleSortArrayAscending dshNames
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Return a copy of the visible sheets in a new workbook
    ' and reference this new workbook.
    swb.Sheets(dshNames).Copy
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    
    ' Order the sheets in the new workbook by the sheet names array.
    OrderSheetsByList dwb, dshNames
    
    ' Export the new workbook to PDF (adjust the properties) and close it.
    dwb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=dFilePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "The following visible sheets were exported to PDF:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Join(dshNames, vbLf), vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the names of the visible sheets of a workbook
'               in a string array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function VisibleSheetNamesInArray(ByVal wb As Workbook) As String()
    Dim shCount As Long: shCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    Dim shNames() As String: ReDim shNames(1 To shCount)
    Dim sh As Object, n As Long
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then: n = n + 1: shNames(n) = sh.Name
    Next sh
    If n < shCount Then ReDim Preserve shNames(1 To n)
    VisibleSheetNamesInArray = shNames
End Function
```

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Sorts an array (in place) in ascending order.
' Remarks:      Slow. Not recommended on a large dataset (>1K).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub BubbleSortArrayAscending(ByRef Arr As Variant) ' note the 'ByRef' (in place)
    Dim LB As Long: LB = LBound(Arr)
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(Arr)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Temp As Variant
    For i = LB To UB - 1
        For j = i To UB
            If Arr(i) > Arr(j) Then
                Temp = Arr(i): Arr(i) = Arr(j): Arr(j) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Moves specific sheets to the end of their workbook ('wb')
'               ordering them by their order in a list ('SheetNames').
' Remarks:      The list can be an array, a collection or an array list.
'               Note that the keys or items of a dictionary are also arrays.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub OrderSheetsByList(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal SheetNames As Variant)
    Dim shCount As Long: shCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    Dim shName As Variant
    For Each shName In SheetNames
        wb.Sheets(shName).Move After:=wb.Sheets(shCount)
    Next shName
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I specify the same print range from each sheet please? e.g. ws.Range("A1:T396")